# Aggregating data from daily to monthly, where each column contains data for a day, and each row represents coordinates

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a large dataframe where the first two columns are longitude and latitude values (making each row represent a point of a specific longitude and latitude), and the succeeding columns are daily data for a long period of time (couple of years). As such, the dataframe is very large.

It looks like this:
[large dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uja8K.png)

Is there a way to transform this dataframe to a monthly one?

- First I want to get the total of each month per year,
- Then I want to get the average of the totals of each month, eventually getting a dataframe with 14 columns: lon, lat, january, february, ..., december.

Is this possible?

I was able to do this when my data only spanned one year using the following code:

```
mymonthlydata$`1`=apply(mydailydata[3:33],1,sum)
```

where I did this for each month (columns 3 to 33 are the days of january for example), but now that I have multiple years, I am not quite sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated, even just pointing me to the right direction. Thank you.

**Some sample data that mimics OP's screenshot that can be used**

```
dt <- data.table::data.table(lon = (0:9)+abs(rnorm(10)), lat = -89.5)[, as.character(seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "1 days")) := abs(rnorm(10)/10^8)]

str(dt)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2559 variables:
#  $ lon       : num  0.702 1.77 3.55 4.294 4.712 ...
#  $ lat       : num  -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5 -89.5
#  $ 2015-01-01: num  0.00000000485 0.00000000474 0.0000000101 0.00000001026 0.00000000282 ...
#  $ 2015-01-02: num  0.00000000485 0.00000000474 0.0000000101 0.00000001026 0.00000000282 ...
#  $ 2015-01-03: num  0.00000000485 0.00000000474 0.0000000101 0.00000001026 0.00000000282 ...
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide some part of your data. As your data is large, try `dput(yourdataname, c(6,6))` and post result of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sample data that mimics OP's screenshot**

```
dt <- data.table(lon = (0:9)+abs(rnorm(10)), lat = -89.5)[, as.character(seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2021-12-31"), by = "1 days")) := abs(rnorm(10)/10^8)]
```

**data.table solution**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# setDT(dt) needed only if you have a data.frame (my sample is already a data.table)

dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = c("lon", "lat"), variable.name = "date")
dt_long[, `:=` (year = year(date), month = month(date, label = T, abbr = F)), by = date]

dt_long_sum <- dt_long[, .(sum = sum(value)), by = .(lon, lat, year, month)]
dt_long_mean <- dt_long_sum[, .(mean = mean(sum)), by = .(lon, lat, month)]

dcast(dt_long_mean, lon + lat ~ month, value.var = "mean")
```

**results**

```
#        lon   lat        January       February          March          April            May           June           July         August      September        October
#  1: 0.7016 -89.5 0.000000150444 0.000000137272 0.000000150444 0.000000145591 0.000000150444 0.000000145591 0.000000150444 0.000000150444 0.000000145591 0.000000150444
#  2: 1.7702 -89.5 0.000000147013 0.000000134141 0.000000147013 0.000000142270 0.000000147013 0.000000142270 0.000000147013 0.000000147013 0.000000142270 0.000000147013
#  3: 3.5504 -89.5 0.000000313048 0.000000285639 0.000000313048 0.000000302950 0.000000313048 0.000000302950 0.000000313048 0.000000313048 0.000000302950 0.000000313048
#  4: 4.2941 -89.5 0.000000318180 0.000000290321 0.000000318180 0.000000307916 0.000000318180 0.000000307916 0.000000318180 0.000000318180 0.000000307916 0.000000318180
#  5: 4.7121 -89.5 0.000000087354 0.000000079705 0.000000087354 0.000000084536 0.000000087354 0.000000084536 0.000000087354 0.000000087354 0.000000084536 0.000000087354
#  6: 5.6789 -89.5 0.000000202693 0.000000184945 0.000000202693 0.000000196154 0.000000202693 0.000000196154 0.000000202693 0.000000202693 0.000000196154 0.000000202693
#  7: 6.4409 -89.5 0.000000168332 0.000000153593 0.000000168332 0.000000162902 0.000000168332 0.000000162902 0.000000168332 0.000000168332 0.000000162902 0.000000168332
#  8: 8.3095 -89.5 0.000000037445 0.000000034166 0.000000037445 0.000000036237 0.000000037445 0.000000036237 0.000000037445 0.000000037445 0.000000036237 0.000000037445
#  9: 8.8061 -89.5 0.000000051242 0.000000046756 0.000000051242 0.000000049589 0.000000051242 0.000000049589 0.000000051242 0.000000051242 0.000000049589 0.000000051242
# 10: 9.2667 -89.5 0.000000338410 0.000000308779 0.000000338410 0.000000327493 0.000000338410 0.000000327493 0.000000338410 0.000000338410 0.000000327493 0.000000338410
#           November       December
#  1: 0.000000145591 0.000000150444
#  2: 0.000000142270 0.000000147013
#  3: 0.000000302950 0.000000313048
#  4: 0.000000307916 0.000000318180
#  5: 0.000000084536 0.000000087354
#  6: 0.000000196154 0.000000202693
#  7: 0.000000162902 0.000000168332
#  8: 0.000000036237 0.000000037445
#  9: 0.000000049589 0.000000051242
# 10: 0.000000327493 0.000000338410
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going above and beyond and for making a sample data. I think this will do the trick!

If you dont mind me asking, do you know how to do it if I wanted to stop at getting the totals for each month? The data would then have 12 columns for each year.


tysm for helping. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: You can achieve that the same way, but than dcast on `dt_long_sum` in my example on both year + month. `dcast(dt_long_sum, lon + lat ~ year + month, value.var = "sum")`